# how to add sliding menu to on the activtity which extend tabactivity in android

Tags: android, slidingmenu, tabactivity

How to add sliding menu to the activity which are not added in the sliding menu and on activity which extends tab Activity

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use fragments instead of activity it is the best solution.

Comment: you can use support library and put this <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mhp.testwebview"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_epub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" > the parent of your layout

Comment: @MHP  but my activity extends tab activity and all other activities open as a child activity inside  tabs. means i have multiple nested activities inside tab. please tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: @james But my  tab activity and all other activity open as a child activity in it

Comment: it is not matter.still you can use it

Comment: @MHP   but i am getting error....can you send me code to do that..?

Comment: put your xml then i will wdit it

Comment: @MHP sir stackoverflow shows error when i post code can u send me link to inherit this feature in my project it very important for me.I'll be veryt thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change you main xml to something like this.(before do this,right click on your project->android tools->add support library-do this work twice-)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" >

    <!-- you main xml,all of your xml -->
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".Tab_login" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:text="Register" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Log In" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="free User" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:text="Roaming" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

THE RESULT PIC:
[image]

Comment: should i change anything in my java file?

Comment: at first,no,maybe later

Comment: yes it show,just touch from left to right.now I am using this in my project.

Comment: it is not showing sliding menu sir. can u send me link to show sliding menu on activity which extends tabactivity

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mhp.example"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <!--you main xml,all of your xml-->
</RelativeLayout>


<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/logoshadow" 
    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="461dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Tab_login"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blank_buttons"
        android:text="Register" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blank_buttons"
        android:text="Log In"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blank_buttons"
        android:text="free User" />
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blank_buttons"
        android:text="Roaming" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I edit my answer ,copy that xml to your project.it works