# how to create Sliding Menu in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Hello guys I'm trying to create a sliding menu ...

I got the Tutorial From Android hive ...
[Sliding Menu tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

My problem is how to create sliding menu like 
this image

[image] ...

Please help me to Create one Like This Image 
thank you in advance 
I'm suffering from this problem From 1 month I googled but got nothing

Comment: hi use add multiple view for listview refer below link http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 1):

SlidingDrawer hides content out of the screen and allows the user to drag a handle to bring the content on screen

See this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this library : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: i saw This But I dont Know How TO use...Where To add Items n All

Answer (score 0):

you can use android support library it is very simple to use,see **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25441009/3553815)**
you can create your slide menu everything that you want.
Note that you should add support library to your project(right click on project ->android tools->add support library , do this twice)

Answer (score 0):

you can add  [this library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) into your project

Implementation is pretty much easy

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    // menu.removeAllViews();
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);

    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);

    menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Where To Add Items ,Where To Put My User_image Name Layout ...using This Library

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom list view with a text view and image view than inflate it in on createview

Answer (score 0):

apply and  implement sliding menu to work in android

> `      ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
>           actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

```
    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    //menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SampleListFragment())
      .commit();

    menu.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame1);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.menu_frame1, new SampleListFragment())
      .commit();



return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

`

Comment: ..please Explain ME ..Where To Add Items ...ExplainME step by step...How to add image layout in slide menu